# How to get rid of Null or "" in VBA Ms access

Tags: json, vba, ms-access

See how you can help to get rid of the null value or "" if the code below does not find a value in the record source, I tried the IsEmpty it is not even accepted in VBA:

```
Tax.Add Nz(DLookup("TaxClassB", "QryJson", "InvoiceID =" & Me.InvoiceID & " AND ItemesID =" & CStr(i)), "")
```

Comment: Is `ItemesID` a string or number like invoice ID?  Can you elaborate more on the code please

Comment: itemesID are squence numbers like 1,2,3, 4 etc

Comment: If ItemesID is a number type field, why use CStr() function? What value do you want to save if DLookup returns Null?

Comment: ItemesID is not negotiable it has to be there to show the product line number as per tax requirement , without using CStr() then json will only showing One product line instead of the line by line . For example if there 100 lines json string will show all lines sequentially , but if you disregard CStr function Json can never show all line products , but only one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you could do something along the lines of the following sub routine:

```
Private Sub TryAddTaxClasses(invoiceID As String, itemesID As String)

Dim criteria As String: criteria = "TaxClassB <> '' AND TaxClassB IS NOT NULL"
If invoiceID <> "" Then criteria = criteria & " AND InvoiceID=" & invoiceID
If itemesID <> "" Then criteria = criteria & " AND ItemesID=" & itemesID

Dim rst As DAO.Recordset: Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT TaxClassB FROM QryJson WHERE " & criteria, dbOpenSnapshot)
rst.MoveFirst

Do While Not rst.EOF
    Tax.Add rst!TaxClassB
    rst.MoveNext
Loop

rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing

End Sub
```

Call it as follows for a specific / single record:

```
TryAddTaxClasses(Me.InvoiceID, CStr(i))
```

or pass through null strings for either or both arguments, which will cause the tax classes to be added for all the matches it makes:

```
TryAddTaxClasses("", "")
```

For anything other than quick, rough and ready code, I'd seriously recommend avoiding the use of DLookup. It causes more trouble than its worth. For example, its shortcomings can be read here > http://allenbrowne.com/ser-42.html

Instead, I tend to use recordset methods, or use my own "ELookup" domain functions similar to the ones on that allenbrowne page.

Answer (score 0):

Finally this has sorted out my problem:

```
Tax.Add Nz(DLookup("TaxClassB", "QryJson", "InvoiceID =" & Me.InvoiceID & " AND ItemesID =" & CStr(i)), "")
```

The amendments required are as follows:

```
Dim myVariant As Variant 
If (myVariant = Empty) Then 
End If
```

After the above declaration then my new code will look like below:

```
Tax.Add Nz(DLookup("TaxClassB", "QryJson", "InvoiceID =" & Me.InvoiceID & " AND ItemesID =" & CStr(i)), myVariant)
```